# Друзья! Подcкажите, в чём может быть разгадка странного (для меня) поведения clang-format?

Tags: c, code-style, clang

Корректирую стиль кода файлов проекта командой:

```
clang-format -style=google -i *.h *.c
```

или

```
clang-format --style=google -i *.h *.c
```

При этом в одних файлах он делает следующее изменения:

```
char* str -> char *str
```

а в других оставляет `char* str`

Чем можно объяснить такое поведение программы?